# Mongoose Typescript Image Upload (Mongo, express, node) Where should i start?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, file-upload

Images will be less than 16mb in size, i am using mongoDB, node, and express. Where should i start? I already created **route**, **model**, **controller**, **service** and **Joi validation** files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the 3rd party services to store the image like amazon s3. Just upload the image on the cloud and store the link on the database. You can find tons of tutorials on this.